# Fastest way to filter objects in array by their value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, filter

Here is my array of objects:

```
var arr = [
    {name:"Mike", age:17},
    {name:"John", age:21},
    {name:"Sam", age:32},
    {name:"Mark", age:23}
]
```

For instance I have hundredth of thousands of objects in this array.

**What is the fastest way to filter it by age (greatest to least)?**

Here is my expected output:

```
var arr = [
    {name:"Sam", age:32},
    {name:"Mark", age:23}
    {name:"John", age:21},
    {name:"Mike", age:17},      
]
```

Comment: filter `greatest to least` sounds more like sort. What is expected output?

Comment: You might want to check out something like Lodash (https://egghead.io/lessons/core-javascript-introduction-to-lodash)

Comment: It's not filtering, it's sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need is sorting. So you could try something like this:

```
// for sorting them from the greatest to the lower
function compare(a,b) {
   return b.age-a.age;
}

arr.sort(compare);
```

If you want to sort them from the lower to the greatest, you have to use the following `compare`

```
function compare(a,b) {
   return a.age-b.age;
}
```

Please have a look here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xsuhhmpr/).

Comment: your code sorted from the least to greatest, not greatest to least

Comment: Shorter: `return a.age - b.age;`